# How to Place Two Different Types of Time Stamps in One Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need following two types of time stamps in one sheet.

1. Time stamp in one cell when any of the cell updated in the same
   sheet(not workbook)
2. Cell-wise time stamp for the set of cells/column.

**Script I am using for the 1st time stamp is:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
   e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getRange('G2')
       .setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy at HH:mm");
}
```

**Script I am using for the 2nd time stamp is:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if ([3].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
    e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

The problem is, above scripts are not working together. They conflict. Is there any solution to this concern?

Is it possible to combine both scripts? or Is it possible by any formula rather than scripts?

[FIND THE WORKSHEET WITH EDIT ACCESS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yo-9AFTO3BrfiuUTMVzQpnKO0CnfUKjgHSSHUB_HKRs/).

Appreciate to any help.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried combining the scripts yourself? It's definitely possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to combine them.

Someone has combined them below but it is limited to one specific sheet. I need it in a way that applies to all sheets of a workbook. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of what you are having problems with. Have you tried physically combining them? And then you can just add an if statement to the first one so that you make sure that it will only input the timestamp if the cell that was edited is located on the particular sheet. (so that it won't just update any time any cell on the spreadsheet is edited)

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
    if (sheet.getName() === "Sheet Name"){
        sheet.getRange('G2').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy at HH:mm");
    }
    if ([3].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
        e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(new Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working on the specific sheet only. What if I want to apply it to all the sheets in the workbook? Or How can I add multiple sheet names in the script? Also, is it possible to add more than one column to check edits and update the time stamp when any of them being edited?

Comment: Can you please solve my query [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551941/how-to-create-timestamp-in-google-sheet-for-multiple-cells-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551941/how-to-create-timestamp-in-google-sheet-for-multiple-cells-update) @Sebastian

Comment: @ziganotschka Can you please check my query and help me out? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551941/how-to-create-timestamp-in-google-sheet-for-multiple-cells-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551941/how-to-create-timestamp-in-google-sheet-for-multiple-cells-update)

Answer (score 0):

### Are your triggers installable?

In this case you should give the functions **different names**, because installable triggers apply for all `.gs` files in a project and cause problems, if there a two functions with the same name within the project, even if they are located in different `.gs` files.

In any case, if you want to carry out different tasks `onEdit()`, you should combine them all inside of one `onEdit()` function, as was already pointed out.