# How to create timestamp in Google sheet for multiple cells update?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I have combined both the scripts in a way that reflects in all the sheets in a workbook now.

UPDATED SCRIPT HERE:

```
   function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
       {sheet.getRange('G3').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy at HH:mm");
    }
    if ([2,3,4,5].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1)
    {sheet.getRange('F6:F').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy at HH:mm");
    }
}
```

My query is:

When any of the B,C,D,E columns get edited, the time stamp noted in the respective cell in column F.

[FIND THE WORKSHEET WITH EDIT ACCESS.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yo-9AFTO3BrfiuUTMVzQpnKO0CnfUKjgHSSHUB_HKRs/)

I have tried but it reflects in all the cell of column G now. Can anybody please help.

Comment: Change `G3` to `F3`?

Comment: That timestamp is working fine. It should be in G3. I am concerned about the timestamp noted in Column F. I had tried editing script last week. But it's not working as I need. Now it is working like when any of column B,C,D,E get edited, column F notes the timestamp. But every update reflects in all the cells of F column. This glitch makes the timestamp meaningless. What I need is every update timestamped in respective cells of column F. Can you fix the script? You can check the script project named Combined.

Comment: @TheMaster can you please help me?

Comment: @bhargav-rao can you please help me?

Comment: [Edit] to show your latest script here. Your current script will only update if C is edited, the respective F cell row will have the date. I don't see how every cell in F is updated.

Comment: @TheMaster I have updated the script. Please review again.

Comment: answered`````````````````​`````````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the edited row, you can use `e.range.rowStart`. With that, you can get the current F row range:

```
sheet.getRange('F'+e.range.rowStart)
```

Comment: Thank you @TheMaster. It's the perfect solution.